# Show custom prompbox html and pass result to php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a table where it displays the list of users. Every user has a message button. on click of message button, I want to show a custom prompt box where user will be able to type a message. On click of submit, typed message will be sent to php page.

```
<div style="overflow: auto;height: 400px; width: 100%;">
   <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Package</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Referring Agent</th>
            <th>Action</th>
       </tr>
       <?php if(!empty($records)){
            foreach($records as $k=>$v){
       ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php echo $v['id']; ?></td>
        <td><h3><a href="#"><?php echo $v['package']; ?></a></h3></td>
        <td><?php echo $v['submit_date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v['agent']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <div class="pagging">
                <a href="?id=<?php echo $v['id'];?>">Message</a>
            </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
    <?php  
        }
     }else{
    ?>
   <tr>
        <td colspan="5" align='center'><?php echo "No record added yet"; ?>
   </tr>
   <?php 
     } 
   ?>


                                <!--<tr class="odd">
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td><h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</a></h3></td>
                                    <td>12.05.09</td>
                                    <td>Administrator</td>
                                    <td>
                                    <div class="pagging">
                                    <a href="#">Send Notification</a>
                                    </div>
                                    </td>`enter code here`
                                </tr>-->

                            </table>
                            </div>
```

in php i am getting the id by this way and here I want the message typed as well. Kindly help

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id=$_GET['id'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick example how to make one:

```
<input type="button" value="Show" onClick="showDiv()">
```

This is button that will trigger event (show div).

```
<div id="someDiv" style="display: none">
    <form action="file.php" method="POST">
        <textarea name="textArea" rows="4" cols="20"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit message">
    </form>
</div>
```

This is your custom prompt (message).

```
<script>
function showDiv()
{
    var div = document.getElementById('someDiv');
    if (div)
        div.style.display = 'inherit';
}
</script>
```

This is JavaScript function that displays your custom prompt.

What you need to do is add onClick event to button and insert somewhere JavaScript function (better in separate JS file) and hide your prompt in the same HTML document.

Hope that helps!